# Check if biblatex key exists

Tags: biblatex, documentclass-writing

How do I test if an entry bibliography key exists? I have a command that takes a key, but should fall back to handling the argument as just a label if the key doesn't exist.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{bib-key,
    author = {John Smith1 and Bob Smith2},
    title = {Some Random Thing},
    date = {1970}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\citecaptioninner[3]{%
    {\caption[#3 #2. \protect\fullcite{#1}]{#2 \protect\parencite{#1}}}}%
    %{\caption[#3 #2.]{#2}}} % Use this instead if key doesn't exist
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \newcommand\citecaption[2]{%
        \citecaptioninner{#1}{#2}{\figurename\ \thefigure.}%
        \label{fig:#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \citecaption{bib-key}{References bibliography}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \citecaption{just-a-label}{Does not reference bibliography}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex can only know in the second compilation (after a biber run) if a key is a citation key or not. This basically means that you have to try to cite it and then have to accept warnings, that this was not successfull, or will have to cite everything with \nocite{*}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, since in the normal setup (where you don't send LaTeX off to parse the `.bib` file itself), LaTeX only gets to know about `.bib` entries indirectly via the `.bbl` file. This is also what [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [mentions in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551662/check-if-biblatex-key-exists#comment1393173_551662). In particular the only way to check if an entry exists for the LaTeX side is to see if the entry was written to the `.bbl` file by Biber or BibTeX.

`biblatex` has an internal test to see if an entry exists in the `.bbl` file (`\blx@ifdata`) and it is easily possible to make this test accessible. But that test relies on the `.bbl` data.

Hence, the following will only reliably tell you if the entry key exists in the `.bbl` file, i.e. if the entry was already requested by your document. In reality that means that only entry keys that were explicitly `\cite`d or `\nocite{*}`'d are found (and that they are only found after a successful Biber run).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IsFoundBibkeyTF}{\blx@ifdata}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
% we don't cite the existing nussbaum
% obviouslyfakeentry does not exist in biblatex-examples.bib

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{sigfridsson}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{nussbaum}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{obviouslyfakeentry}{T}{F}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//T//F//F]

If you add a `\nocite{*}` into the mix, you will also test `nussbaum`, which wasn't explicitly cited, correctly, but of course `\nocite{*}` means that you add all entries from your `.bib` file to the bibliography, which may be undesirable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IsFoundBibkeyTF}{\blx@ifdata}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
% we don't cite the existing nussbaum
% obviouslyfakeentry does not exist in biblatex-examples.bib

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{sigfridsson}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{nussbaum}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{obviouslyfakeentry}{T}{F}

\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//T//T//F]

It would be possible to issue a `\nocite` only for the entry key you want to check out. This will then pick up entries that were not already cited in your document. But it comes with two *very* big caveats: It will produce a warning for non-existing keys - which is presumably what you want to avoid with this whole thing in the first place. On the other hand it will add the entry to the bibliography if it exists - which may also not be desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IsFoundBibkeyTF}[1]{\nocite{#1}\blx@ifdata{#1}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
% we don't cite the existing nussbaum
% obviouslyfakeentry does not exist in biblatex-examples.bib

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{sigfridsson}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{nussbaum}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{obviouslyfakeentry}{T}{F}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//T//T//F]

plus the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                obviouslyfakeentry
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.
```

in the `.log`.

---

If you want a test that can really tell if an entry key is present in your `.bib` file, you need to skip Biber. You need to parse the `.bib` file from LaTeX yourself.

Here is an implementation that is shamelessly stolen from  Enrico Gregorio's [`usebib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib) package, which extracts entry fields directly from the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bibentrycheck@labels}{}

\def\bec@reuse@find#1#{%
  \lowercase{\def\@tempa{#1}}%
  \ifcsname bec@reuse@type@\@tempa\endcsname
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \begingroup\@makeother\%\makeatother
    \expandafter\bec@reuse@extract
  \fi}

% special types: ignored
\let\bec@reuse@type@preamble\@empty
\let\bec@reuse@type@string\@empty

% extract key
\def\bec@reuse@extract#1{\bec@reuse@extract@entrykey#1\relax\endgroup}
\def\bec@reuse@extract@entrykey#1,#2\relax{\listgadd{\bibentrycheck@labels}{#1}}

\newcommand{\bibinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=10
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\@
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\bec@reuse@find
  \catcode`\@=\active \input{#1.bib}\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\IsFoundBibkeyTF}[1]{\ifinlist{#1}{\bibentrycheck@labels}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
% we don't cite the existing nussbaum
% obviouslyfakeentry does not exist in biblatex-examples.bib

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{sigfridsson}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{nussbaum}{T}{F}

\IsFoundBibkeyTF{obviouslyfakeentry}{T}{F}

\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//T//T//F]

Note that this requires you to call `\bibinput{<bib filename without extension>}` again on all files you add with `\addbibresource`. (It seems possible to patch `\addbibresource` to do that automatically, but that opens another can of worms.)

---

If I'm allowed the final comment, I don't think it is good style to write a `\cite`-related macro that tests if its input might be an entry key and behaves differently if it apparently isn't. In the MWE from the question it seems the first argument of `\citecaption` is used for several things: It sets a label *and* is (possibly) the entry key of something you want to `\cite`. I suggest you split these jobs into several arguments (if you like with a key-value interface). That makes it clear from the outset what is a label and what is the entry key you cite. In particular I'd find it odd to call `\citecaption`, which quite clearly implies to me something is cited, with arguments that cause it not to attempt to cite anything.